# Wrong image size after screenshot from a .html file with Google Chrome headless mode

Tags: google-chrome-headless

I'm using the `Google Chrome Headless` mode to generate some *.jpg based on *.html files like this:

```
google-chrome 
--headless
--disable-gpu
--hide-scrollbars
--screenshot="preview.jpg"
--windows-size=1200,900
--default-background-color=0
index.html
```

Issue is the `windows-size` is not respected at all and the generated *.jpg are 800x600 (whereas it should be 1200x900).

Please note that my HTML files are a simple `<div>` set to 1200x900 containing a background image.

Do you know why ?

Thanks.

Comment: I have the same problem today and just posted about it. It seems there was a major upgrade last month to headless. I downloaded the new version just over the weekend. I didn't find out until I ran my code and, thereby, screwed up one of my websites. :(

The doc says you can run it as headless=old but that doesn't work. I completely purged chrome and installed a version from nearly a year ago. Still broken. I have no idea how to proceed. It's good to know, though, that it's not just me.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it seems that --window-size is ignored nowadays and this also has happened on my Linux server. The solution for me was to remove windows size and simply add:

```
--force-device-scale-factor=1.5
```

into the mix which extends the taken screenshot size by the amount stated.

That is, with a scale factor of 1.5 the screesnhot will have 800*1.5=1200 and 600*1.5=900 pixels as per your request.

On a different -- execution-wise related -- note. If you are on Linux, make sure you pass the --default-background-color argument in hex format embedded within quotes and excluding #, e.g. --default-background-color="1a0c16", as Chrome throws otherwise an "Expected a hex RGB or RGBA value for --default-background-color=0".

So, finally

```
google-chrome 
--headless
--disable-gpu
--hide-scrollbars
--force-device-scale-factor=1.5
--screenshot="preview.jpg"
--default-background-color="ffffff"
index.html
```